# Random errors in applescript?

Tags: applescript

Hello people of stackoverflow. I found your website very useful when making my first script! It is now my turn to ask questions.

I am newbie to programming so I how you can bear with me.

I made this script to make modifying Mac OS easier. I finished it, tested it and it worked. I try to export it as .app but it gives my non-nonsensical errors that I can't fix.

```
set modoption to {"Hold key for special characters", "Change \"Disk Almost Full\" notification threshold", "Install Brew", "}
set modoption to (choose from list modoption with prompt "Select mod:")

if modoption = {"Hold key for special characters"} then
    do shell script "defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true"
else if modoption = {"Change \"Disk Almost Full\" notification threshold"} then
    display dialog "Disk Almost Full notification threshold" default answer "20"
    set notifsize to (text returned of result)
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.diskspaced minFreeSpace " & notifsize
else if modoption = {"Install Brew"} then
    set brewinstallwarning to "This could take several hours."
    display dialog brewinstallwarning with icon caution
    do shell script "/bin/bash -c \"$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)\""
end if
```

It gives me this error:

*Expected “given”, “with”, “without”, other parameter name, etc. but found “mod”.*

So when I remove

> "select mod:"

It gives me this error:

*Expected “,” or “}” but found identifier.*

What did I do wrong?! It worked a minute ago!

Comment: Your script above has an errant quote at the end of the first line: `set modoption to {"Hold key for special characters", "Change \"Disk Almost Full\" notification threshold", "Install Brew", "}` should be `set modoption to {"Hold key for special characters", "Change \"Disk Almost Full\" notification threshold", "Install Brew"}`.  There may be other errors, but you just have to fix them one-by-one, and this one is the first one.

Comment: thank you CJK for your answer! unfortunately, you didn't use the "Answer" function in stack overflow so I can't mark it as answered!

Btw, the code now works, thank you!

Comment: Good point.  I'm used to new users not rewarding answers, likely due to lack of familiarity with SO.  But, since you're willing, that would be great.  I'll transfer my comment to answer-form.

Answer (score 0):

The script contains an errant double-quote at the end of the first line (highlighted in the following code block) as well as the comma immediately preceding it (left unmarked):

```
set modoption to {"Hold key for special characters", "Change \"Disk Almost ↩︎
                   Full\" notification threshold", "Install Brew", ⦗"⦘}
set modoption to (choose from list modoption with prompt "Select mod:")
```

<sup>**Note:** *A carriage return symbol (`↩︎`) has been inserted to indicate where the first line has been divided to span two lines, in order to aid readability.  White space has been added for padding to improve alignment.  Other than that which has been indicated, no other changes were made.*</sup>

**SOLUTION:** Removal of the highlighted double-quote, as well as the comma immediately before it.

---

### About The Errors

> ```
> Expected “given”, “with”, “without”, other parameter name, etc. but found “mod”.
> ```

The presence of this extra double-quote unintentionally forms an additional string item in the list that was being declared.  This list is presumably intended to terminate with `"Install Brew"` as its final item, however, the serendipitous presence of an extra comma adds a further item to the list comprising text beginning after the errant double-quote and encompassing what would otherwise be syntax that spans two lines, all the way to after the word `"prompt"`.  The complete string formed is this:

```
"}
set modoption to (choose from list modoption with prompt "
```

**`select`** happens to be an AppleScript command, albeit not one that's documented.  The nature of AppleScript commands (these usually compile in Script Editor to appear in bold blue typeface) are such that they can accept a *direct* parameter that either immediately follows the command (this is the most usual form) or immediately *precedes* the command.  For example, using the **`exists`** command with *Finder*, one can test for the existence of a folder using these two syntax forms:

```
tell application id "com.apple.finder"
        tell the home directory
               the folder "Downloads" exists --> true
        end tell
end tell
```

or:

```
tell application id "com.apple.finder"
        tell the home directory
               exists the folder "Downloads" --> true
        end tell
end tell
```

The same principle means that the newly-formed, accidental string is then interpreted to be a *direct* parameter for the **`select`** command.  Hence, the first occurrence of a definitively erroneous piece of AppleScript code is the presence of the word `"mod"`, which is a mathematical function.

The expectation of finding words other than `"mod"` by the AppleScript compiler are simply the smallest change one could make to the script so that it no longer generated an error in this part of the code.  `"given"`, `"with"`, `"without"`, etc. are all terms that can follow command names or handler identifiers that indicate a further (*indirect*, or *named*) parameter is to follow.

When you removed the phrase `"\"Select mod:\""`, this led to a different error of the nature:

> ```
> Expected “,” or “}” but found identifier.
> ```

This isn't one of AppleScript's most fine-tuned suggestions for solving an syntax error, as the removal of `"\"Select mod:\""` still leaves the original errant double-quote in play, now with no paired closing double-quote.  This doesn't get acknowledged as a possible solution, and instead, the compiler has jumped a step ahead by putting forward a solution to the seemingly absence closing curly brace that would terminate the list declaration (the original curly brace came after the errant double-quote, so is no longer regarded as syntax, but simply as plain text).

Were you to close the string by inserting a double-quote at the end of the line from which you removed `"\"Select mod:\""`, this would form the following string item:

```
"}
set modoption to (choose from list modoption with prompt )"
```

and this would be a perfectly valid list item to follow the ones that come before it.  The error that is generated at this point is very much of a similar ilk to the one we already had, except that instead of complaining of an unexpected identifier, the compiler now (quite rightly) complains about an unexpected end-of-line:

> Expected “,” or “}” but found end of line.

It's evident at this point that either the list needs to continue its declaration by adding more items to it; or the list needs its declaration to be completed, by closing it off with a curly brace; hence the two possibilities presented to us as valid syntax choices, namely a comma (for a continuing list), or a closing brace (for a completed list).

---

The serial combinations of errors that emerged (or could have potentially emerged) were a serendipitous overlapping set of syntactical happenstances that can easily swamp the best of us struggling to correct an error and sinking deeper into the quick sand of coincidental misfortune.  The odds of one stray double-quote and a comma forming a string that just happens to be positioned before a word that is also an AppleScript command, and so on, are probably not that gigantic, but certainly not that small to make this an everyday way to balls up your code.  Hopefully this deconstruction of each of the errors caught is more useful than it is boring, as I can't actually tell myself at this point.